# Cannot save PySpark dataframe as a parquet file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Complete Python newbie here. I am trying to save a PySpark dataframe as a parquet file, but it's giving me an error. I installed PySpark  PySpark version is 3.3.0, Hadoop version 3.2.2, Java jdk1.8.0_351 on PC and created environment variables, as per https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10. I am using Jupyterlab via Anaconda (Python 3).

```
!pip install pyspark
!pip install yfinance

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

import findspark
findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkTrial").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()

data = yf.download("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
data = data.reset_index()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data) #this like successfully works; data type: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

#Installing Hadoop did not work so I also tried next three lines. Still doesn't work
import os
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']=r"C:\Hadoop"
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351"

df.write.parquet("/tmp/test2.parquet") # this line causes error
```

Error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.write.parquet("/tmp/test2.parquet")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:1140, in DataFrameWriter.parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
   1138     self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
   1139 self._set_opts(compression=compression)
-> 1140 self._jwrite.parquet(path)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.parquet.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:356)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:793)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1867)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:515)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

May I know how and where you are running this code snippet ?
If you are running on your local machine, then you need to setup your HADOOP_HOME.

you can refer to the below docs which will give details around it.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10

Setting HADOOP_HOME on windows:
https://brain-mentors.com/hadoopinstallation/

sample to write a file into parquet:

```
df.write.parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")
```

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems has some more information, as well

Comment: @Shane Thank you, I did not know that I had to set up HADOOP_HOME. I followed the first link and set HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME env variables but it still does not seem to work.  I have edited my post to include full script.